# The api I sent the request to works but returns an error

Tags: angular, api

[image]

Error Detail: [image]

Hello, as you can see in the picture, I am sending a request to the API I wrote. api works but it shows an error even though the response status code is 200, what is the reason for this?

```
Angular Service:   giveCertificate(studentID:number,certificateID:number):Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.post(`https://localhost:6001/Admin/api/Certificates/give?studentID=`+studentID+"&certificateID="+certificateID, { responseType: 'text' });
  }

Angular methot:  giveCertificate(): void {
    if (this.CertificateAssignmentForm.valid) {
      let certificateGive: CertificateGive = new CertificateGive();
      certificateGive = Object.assign({}, this.CertificateAssignmentForm.value);
      
      this.certificateService.giveCertificate(certificateGive.studentID,certificateGive.certificateID)
      .subscribe(response=>{
        if (response.success) {
          this.alertfyService.confirm("Sertifika Öğrenciye Verildi")
        }
       
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: 200 is not an error. All 2xx responses are success responses.

Comment: I've removed the C# part of your question because it's irrelevant. This is an issue somewhere in your Angular code because it's interpreting a success as a failure.

Comment: yes, I know that 200 is a success code, but as you can see in the picture, it returns an error. @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: `200` is the http status code for “everything works fine”, meaning that from a mere transport protocol point of view, packets are sent and received fine. I guess the error is in how the API manages the payload you provided.

Comment: No, Angular/your code (perhaps you have some HTTP pipeline on the Angualr side?) is interpreting it as an error. That's not the same thing as the server returning an error. Not even remotely. Please do not mix these things up.

Comment: So how can I fix this? Why is Angular interpreting this as an error?
@DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Unless you see a problem on the Angular side, I think that deleting the C# code was a bit overzealous. It's not because the response body contains `200` that the actual HTTP response code was 200.

Comment: Who knows? We don't have enough info on the Angular side. Does expanding the console error message show a stack trace?

Comment: @Robby The server is returning 200, the Angular side is logging an error. It seems pretty clear cut to me. If OP made the request to `https://httpstat.us/200` I'm sure they'd see the same issue.

Comment: Can you please share you giveCertificate function of certificateService service? There's a problem there, probably an rxjs error not Angular

Comment: @Robby It appears to just be a print of the  [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) from Angular, not the body of the response. Therefore 200 is what the server is responding with.

Comment: I have added the detail of the error given by Angular as a picture, you can examine it.
@DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: It looks like you're trying to treat plaintext as JSON.

Comment: @FatihErsoy Mr. Fatih, if you are talking about the service part by angular, it is available in the post. If you are talking about the part by .Net, I added it, but unfortunately it has been removed.

Comment: Perhaps [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18672) can help.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWarI tried the information in the source you gave, but unfortunately I could not reach the solution.

Comment: Wait... shouldn't your request be `return this.httpClient.post(`https://localhost:6001/Admin/api/Certificates/give?studentID=`+studentID+"&certificateID="+certificateID, null, { responseType: 'text' });` ? - The second parameter is the body, not the options. You need the options.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Any chance of you connecting remotely?
@DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the request info from the network tab - both the request and response details.

Comment: @Erenimo I just saw that you shared your Angular service, sorry. This error happens because you expect response type as text but there's an error on parsing JSON.

Comment: Actually, I think you might need to specify the content type you want: `this.httpClient.post(localhost:6001/Admin/api/Certificates/give?studentID=+studentID+"&certificateID="+certificateID, null, { headers: { Accept: 'text/plain' }, responseType: 'text' });`

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help. Thanks to @DiplomacyNotWar my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. You're passing options in the place where you should pass the request body. The signature is:

   `post(url, body, options)`
2. You're not requesting `text/plain` from the server, so you're leaving it up to the server what format you want the response in.

Your request should actually look like this (newlines added for clarity):

```
this.httpClient.post(
    "http://localhost:6001/Admin/api/Certificates/give?studentID=+studentID+"&certificateID="+certificateID,
    null,
    { headers: { Accept: 'text/plain' }, responseType: 'text' }
);
```

Here we're specifying that we accept `text/plain` from the server. Then we're telling Angular that the response type is `text`.